# What is specific usage of "to be of service"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Can you let me know specific usage of that expression?

Comment: What does your dictionary say? We are happy to explain problems you have found with definitions, but would rather not be used as a substitute for research

Comment: Could you tell us what, in your dictionary,  the examples and following sentence were, please?

Comment: Of course i found the examples on my dictionary, but i didnt get following sentence - Thank you for giving us this opportunity to be of service. Why the writer use that expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Be of service](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/be-of-service-to-sb)" means to help, but it is used in more restricted contexts. It's rarely used in a form other than the infinitive (so, you're unlikely to hear "X is/was of service"). It's almost always used by the person who would perform/did perform the service (for example, "Let me know if/how I can be of service", "Glad I could be of service") rather than the person receiving it. It's probably most often used in offers of assistance ("How can I be of service?").

In the sentence "Thank you for giving us this opportunity to be of service," there are a couple of reasons why the speaker may have chosen "be of service" over "help":

- it's less direct and therefore more polite
- it may draw some focus away from the fact that the listener needed help and onto the fact that the speaker was able to perform a favor

Comment: EL&U requests that, even with well known words, you should click on the link sign and name a source, such as Merriam-Webster, OED, Etymonline. This can be done by clicking on the 'edit'.

Comment: Thanks, Hugh. I've tried to do this. Where can I read about this and other similar policies?

Answer (score 0):

Typically it means, ["May I help you?"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of+service+to+someone,+be)A very very polite shopkeeper might say,

> Can I be of service, sir,/madam?

A knight errant (or James Bond) might say to a damsel in distress.

> May I be of service?

adding "Glad to be of service" when the problem was resolved.